ParameterInfo.DefaultValue is null for optional value-type parameter
In the code below, when I try to get default value of an optional parameter whose type is a custom value type, I get null. This doesn't make sense to me, since null is not a valid value of type Bar.
public static void Main()
{
    var ctor = typeof(Foo).GetConstructors().First();
    foreach (var paramInfo in ctor.GetParameters())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(paramInfo);
        Console.WriteLine(paramInfo.HasDefaultValue);
        Console.WriteLine(paramInfo.DefaultValue ?? "[default value is null]");
        Console.WriteLine(paramInfo.RawDefaultValue ?? "[default value is null]");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int intVal1 = 3, int intVal2 = default, Bar barVal = default)
    {
    }
}

public struct Bar
{
    public string Value;

    public Bar(string value) { Value = value; }

    public Bar() : this("default constructor") { }

    public override string ToString() =>
        Value == null ? "Bar [value is null]" : $"Bar: {Value}";
}

The code outputs the following:
Int32 intVal1
True
3
3

Int32 intVal2
True
0
0

Bar barVal
True
[default value is null]
[default value is null]

Instead of "[default value is null]", I would have expected "Bar [value is null]".
First of all, is this a bug in .NET? Secondly, how can I get the default value? The code below seems to work for this case, but I don't know whether to trust it because I don't know whether my assumption of paramInfo.HasDefaultValue && paramInfo.ParameterType.IsValueType && paramInfo.DefaultValue == null covers all the cases where I need to use GetDefaultValueOfType.
public static object? GetDefaultParameterValue(ParameterInfo paramInfo)
{
    if (paramInfo.HasDefaultValue)
    {
        var defaultValue = paramInfo.DefaultValue;
        if (paramInfo.ParameterType.IsValueType && defaultValue == null)
        {
            // Seems to happen for custom structs.
            // I don't know why this happens; is it a bug in .NET?
        }
        else
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    return GetDefaultValueOfType(paramInfo.ParameterType);
}

public static object? GetDefaultValueOfType(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsValueType)
    {
        return typeof(ParameterVM)
            .GetMethod(nameof(GetDefaultValueOfTypeGeneric))
            .MakeGenericMethod(type)
            .Invoke(null, null);
    }
    return null;
}

public static T GetDefaultValueOfTypeGeneric<T>()
{
    return default;
}

Note that the answers on Getting DefaultValue for optional Guid through reflection? are not applicable here. Activator.CreateInstance() uses the default constructor, which results in the output "Bar: default constructor", whereas actually constructing a Foo and printing barVal results in "Bar [value is null]".


First of all, is this a bug in .NET?

It is not a bug. It is (somewhat) specified in the ECMA-335 standard.
II.22.9 Constants

The Constant table is used to store compile-time, constant values for
fields, parameters, and properties.
The Constant table has the
following columns:

Type (a 1-byte constant, followed by a 1-byte padding zero); see §II.23.1.16 . The  encoding of Type for the nullref value for
FieldInit in ilasm (§II.16.2) is  ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS with a Value of a
4-byte zero. Unlike uses of  ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS in signatures, this
one is not followed by a type token.
...

Type shall be exactly one of:

ELEMENT_TYPE_BOOLEAN, ELEMENT_TYPE_CHAR, ELEMENT_TYPE_I1, ELEMENT_TYPE_U1, ELEMENT_TYPE_I2, ELEMENT_TYPE_U2, ELEMENT_TYPE_I4, ELEMENT_TYPE_U4, ELEMENT_TYPE_I8, ELEMENT_TYPE_U8, ELEMENT_TYPE_R4, ELEMENT_TYPE_R8,
or ELEMENT_TYPE_STRING;
or ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS with a Value of zero (§II.23.1.16)


The confusing part is implicitly reusing the ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS for both reference and custom value types (which have their own element constant ELEMENT_TYPE_VALUETYPE).
Possible reason for this is that the default value for a struct is always all if its field zeroed out. If we had a large struct with default value explicitly written in the metadata, we would have to waste a lot of space just for 0s that convey no real information - neither to reflection users nor to the runtime.

Secondly, how can I get the default value?

You can add this if you are in reflection context:
if (paramInfo.ParameterType.IsValueType && paramInfo.HasDefaultValue) {
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(paramInfo.ParameterType);
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}

EDIT:
As mentioned in your comment the Activator.CreateInstance will call the default parameterless constructor which will yield a different value than the default one in your case.
One way I can think of to get the value when we just know the Type would be to write an extension method (EDIT: included a lot of edge cases from a variety of answers to this question):
public static class TypeExtensions {
    private static MethodInfo s_getDefaultTypeGeneric =
        typeof(TypeExtensions).GetMethod(
            nameof(TypeExtensions.GetDefaultTypeValueCore),
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> s_defaultValues = new();
    private static T GetDefaultTypeValueCore<T>() => default(T);

    public static object GetDefaultTypeValue(this Type type) {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(type);
        if (type.ContainsGenericParameters)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No default type value for open generic type {type.Name}");
        if (type == typeof(void))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No default type value for System.Void");

        if (!type.IsValueType) return null;

        var defaultValue = s_defaultValues.GetOrAdd(type,
            t => s_getDefaultTypeGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, null));
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

General Use:
var defaultValue = typeof(Bar).GetDefaultTypeValue();

in our reflection-context:
if (paramInfo.ParameterType.IsValueType && paramInfo.HasDefaultValue) {
    var instance = paramInfo.ParameterType.GetDefaultTypeValue();
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}


Very interesting. Does this specification of the constants table also prevent them from returning the zeroed-out struct from ParameterInfo.DefaultValue?

The trouble with Activator.CreateInstance is that it will use the default constructor, not the zeroed-out struct. In my example, the output would be "Bar: default constructor" instead of the correct "Bar [value is null]".

@hypehuman it is not written explicitly. But as you can see, the constant values that are written in the actual metadata are either primitives, a string or a nullref indicator which is reused for both reference types and value types. Bad thing is that we have to do a bit of work to get the real default value if we have a struct.

@hypehuman good point about Activator.CreateInstance (and one that goes against most known solutions here on SO). My last edit seems to address most (if not all) cases for an extension method for this to work as expected.
